# D3js projection EPSG code for ogr2ogr?

Tags: d3.js, gdal, topojson, ogr

I use d3js for vector projection, it's something such as `d3.geo.mercator()`:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(150)
        .translate([0, 0]);
```

I also use ogr2ogr for raster projections, it's something such as `epsg:3857`:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 ...
```

As I must have the both matching perfectly...

**Is there a place where we can find for each [d3js projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/) to which [EPSG projection code](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/) it must be associated ?**

Comment: I believe the answer is no.